# Bootstrap not switching back and forth repeatedly between the same tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently I've come across this (http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/e-mail-interface) snippet and as I started to experiment with it I noticed that there is some odd behaviour regarding switching back and forth to tabs.

Essentionally what I expierence is that when the user switches to tabs with a different hash location, the switching works as expected (#inbox -> #compose -> #trash -> #inbox). However in the event that user switches repeatedly between the same tabs i.e.  #inbox -> #compose -> #inbox it doesn't perform the switch.

Is there anything in particulair that causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the DOM isn't supported by the [Bootstrap Tab stuff](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

The 'Compose' button should be a part of the navbar `ul`.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li style="padding-right:20px;border-right:1px solid #ccc;">
            <p>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" style="height: 35px; color:#fff;" href="#compose" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Compose</a>
            </p>
        </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#inbox" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    Inbox <span class="label label-success">10</span>
                    .....
```

As opposed to:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="btn-compose pull-left">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" href="#compose" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Compose</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#inbox" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    Inbox <span class="label label-success">10</span>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/jkxszq0b/4/) It also fixes the problem the original has where clicking 'Compose' on a small screen would open the Inbox.